# Inheriting a class from static library causing undefined symbols in objective c

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, static-libraries

I have a static library in my work space. In that there is Apple.h & .m file In the .h file i defined two @interface Apple : NSObject & @interface GreenApple : NSObject

In the same work space i have another iOS application project which references this static library. In this application When i inherit GreenApple i get 'Undefined symbols' error for both device and simulator build. But, there is no error if i inherit from Apple.

Across project should the imported .h and inherited class has to be same Or my GreenApple inheritance should work though it is under Apple.h file?

**Edit**

To test the theory i renamed the file to match the error class, but still same error. Actual implementation is given below from file CMSGMealMenuItem.h.

```
@interface CMSGMealMenu : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CMSGMealType mealType;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *orderStartTime;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDate *orderEndTime;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *items;

@end

@interface CMSGMealMenuItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *itemId;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *itemDescription;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *itemSummary;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSNumber *itemPrice;

@end
```

Always CMSGMealMenuItem inheritance throws undefined symbol error, whether .h file name matches are not. But, i couldn't spot how that is different from CMSGMealMenu definition? which doesn't throw any error if inherit from it.

**Edit**

Referring CMSGMealMenuItem as method parameter doesn't shows any build error, only errors if i inherit.

This works

```
@interface MSMealMenuItem : CMSGMealMenu

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *quantity;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAddedToCart;

+ (MSMealMenuItem *) createMSMealMenuItemFromCMSGMealMenuItem:(CMSGMealMenuItem *)CMSGMealMenuItem;

@end
```

If i change the parent to CMSGMealMenuItem throws undefined symbol error as below either i build for device or simulator.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMSGMealMenuItem", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MSMealMenuItem in MSMealMenuItem.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CMSGMealMenuItem", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MSMealMenuItem in MSMealMenuItem.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Do you actually **link against** the library?

Comment: Yes, as you can see that inheriting from Apple or from any other class which also shared the .h file name works.

Comment: Linking is different to including...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. I was just defining my @interface with suitable properties and methods, deferring the implementation. When CMSGMealMenu @implementation was auto generated at the time of file creation, I missed to put @implementation for my explicitly introduced @interface CMSGMealMenuItem.

I thought as long as .h is defined and linked it should be good to compile, as that is what we import. But it seems not as the case during inheritance though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your app with the static library which contains `CMSGMealMenuItem`.

See: http://www.xs-labs.com/en/archives/articles/xcode-static-libraries/